# How can I install all available extras (if any) with pip?

Tags: pip

I've started adding an "all" extra to my packages which contains all extras:

```
from setuptools import setup

requires_all = requires_aws + requires_datetime + requires_image + requires_io + requires_tests
setup(
    extras_require={
        "all": requires_all,
        "aws": requires_aws,
        "datetime": requires_datetime,
        "image": requires_image,
        "io": requires_io,
        "tests": requires_tests,
    }
)
```

The reason why I do so is because I, as a user, usually want to install every available extra. I don't want to have to care about this as my disk space is usually not a limiting factor.

Besides the package creator adding such an "all" extra, is there another possibility to install all extras with pip?

Comment: No there isn't. `[all]` used to be part of [PEP-426](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#extras-optional-dependencies) but it got withdrawn. But if you usually want all extras, are they actually extras?

Comment: I can show you a package where `[all]` is rather meaningless: [SQLObject](https://pypi.org/project/SQLObject/). Extras list [different database drivers](http://sqlobject.org/download.html#drivers) and I cannot imagine a person who would need all drivers at once including different Postgres and MySQL drivers.

Comment: @NilsWerner I, as a developer on my local machine. I don't want the extras in production.

Comment: @phd That is not the point. I am saying I have this use case often. That you have a single case where you don't have it doesn't mean that I don't have it often.

Comment: But don't you define your dependencies and dev-dependencies in a requirements or pyproject file?

Comment: No, I don't do that.