# `pip install` with all extras

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

How does one `pip install` with all extras? I'm aware that doing something like:

```sh
pip install -e .[docs,tests,others]
```

is an option. But, is it possible to do something like:

```sh
pip install -e .[all]
```

This question is similar to [setup.py/setup.cfg install all extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609869/setup-py-setup-cfg-install-all-extras). However, the answer there requires that the `setup.cfg` file be edited. Is it possible to do it **without** modifying `setup.py` or `setup.cfg`?

Comment: [No way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428272/how-can-i-install-all-available-extras-if-any-with-pip#comment106900145_60428272) until the author of the package declares `all` extras in `setup.py`.

Comment: Is there a proper way to declare `all` in `setup.py` without repeating all the dependencies in the other categories of extras?

Comment: `docs=[…]; tests=[…]; others=[…]; all=docs + tests + others; setup(…, extras_require={'all': all, 'docs': docs, …} …)`

Comment: An example from the real world: https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/a9b17f74adf0747a2bbaee13638cd7679af7c34a/setup.py#L114_L132, https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/a9b17f74adf0747a2bbaee13638cd7679af7c34a/setup.py#L168_L180

Comment: @phd Got it, thanks!

Comment: @phd I will take this for an answer if you compose one.

Comment: Proof that this doesn't exist: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5039

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to [install all extras] without modifying setup.py or setup.cfg?

No until the author of the package declares all extras in setup.py. Something like

```
docs = […]
tests = […]
others = […]
all = docs + tests + others

setup(
    …,
    extras_require = {
        'all': all,
        'docs': docs,
        'tests': tests,
        'others': others,
    },
    …,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way:

```
import itertools

extras_require = {
   'foo': [],
   'bar': [],
}
extras_require['all'] = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(extras_require.values()))
```

Comment: Wouldn't just `extras_require['all'] = list(extras_require.values())` suffice?

Comment: The values here are lists themselves, you're making a list of lists, whereas you want a list of all the items in those lists.

Comment: Ah, yes of course.

Comment: @JensunRavichandran `extras_require["all"] = [dep for deps in extras_require.values() for dep in deps]`