# Can I define a package extra that depends on another extra from the same package?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am building a small Python package, for which I have configured a couple of *extras*; in my `setup.cfg`, I have the following:

```
[options.extras_require]
test =
    coverage>=5,<6
    pytest>=6,<7
    pytest-cov>=2.8.1,<3
lint =
    flake8
```

This works fine; I can do `pip install .`, `pip install .[test]`, `pip install .[lint]` or `pip install .[test,lint]` in my package directory, and it will install the right things.

Now, I would like to create a new extra, `dev`, so that `pip install .[dev]` implies installing both the `test` and `lint` extras. Is this possible? How?

I have tried e.g.

```
dev =
    .[test]
    .[lint]
```

but this results in a parser error. I have also tried referring to my package name explicitly instead of `.` in the dependency list, but then it starts downloading old versions from PyPI instead of using the current directory.

Comment: [Its' possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64791668/7976758) in `setup.py` but I don't know a way to do that in `setup.cfg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values):

```
[options.extras_require]
test =
  coverage>=5,<6
  pytest>=6,<7
  pytest-cov>=2.8.1,<3
lint =
  flake8
dev =
  %(test)s
  %(lint)s
```